# update variable inside loop returns the same value

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a loop where I have to set two consecutive numbers.  The first number is the loop counter and the next one is the loop counter + 1.  In the next loop iteration, I would like for it to continue from the last number used.  It keeps picking up the next loop counter not the + 1.  And not sure why.

I have tried to set the variable on the top of the loop and at the end and still getting the same results.

```
Example:
precedence = 3
att_ip = ["1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2"]
expected results:
 precedence is 3
 precedence plus index 3
 precedence plus index + 1 is  4
 
 precedence is 5
 precedence plus index 5
 precedence plus index + 1 is  6
 
Actual results:
 precedence is 3
 precedence plus index 3
 precedence plus index + 1 is  4

 precedence is 3
 precedence plus index 4
 precedence plus index + 1 is  5
```

```
{% for att_ip in att_ips %}
{% set precedence = precedence + 1 %}

precedence is {{ precedence }}
precedence plus index {{ precedence + loop.index0 }}
precedence plus index +1 is  {{ precedence + loop.index }}


{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a variable in a loop like that; see the Jinja documentation on scoping behavior in the [assignments](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#assignments) section:

> Please keep in mind that it is not possible to set variables inside a block and have them show up outside of it. This also applies to loops. The only exception to that rule are if statements which do not introduce a scope. As a result the following template is not going to do what you might expect:
>
> ```
> {% set iterated = false %}
> {% for item in seq %}
>     {{ item }}
>     {% set iterated = true %}
> {% endfor %}
> {% if not iterated %} did not iterate {% endif %}
> ```
>
> It is not possible with Jinja syntax to do this

There are some ways to work around this, but isn't `{{ precedence + loop.index }}` always going to give you the value you want?

---

You could do this:

```
{% set initial_precedence = precedence %}
{% for att_ip in att_ips %}
{% set precedence = initial_precedence + loop.index %}

precedence is {{ precedence }}
precedence plus index {{ precedence + loop.index0 }}
precedence plus index +1 is  {{ precedence + loop.index }}
{% endfor %}
```

This will produce as output:

```
precedence is 4
precedence plus index 4
precedence plus index +1 is  5

precedence is 5
precedence plus index 6
precedence plus index +1 is  7
```

Comment: loop.index is set correctly, my issue is that I need to figure out how to set the precedence variable and not sure how do this.

Comment: Can't you just `{% set localprecedence = precedence + loop.index %}`?

Comment: This still give me the same result nothing changed

Comment: I guess I'm not clear on what you want. It seems as if the value of `{{ precedence + loop.index }}` is *exactly* the value you're looking for, and it's not clear from your question (or your comments) why you can't simply use the expression.

Comment: I want the next iteration of precedence.   `{{ precedence + loop.index }}` is working but this is not what I want.  On every iteration precedence does not change.  How can I set precedence inside the loop?

Comment: I've updated this answer with one option for setting `precedence` inside the loop.